# Retrieve Value from Dynamic Control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I use this code to generate dynamic controls in MVC.

I am working on MVC Application. The Control names are stored in database like there is 5 rows that contains control name (ex. texbox, dropdown) and I retrieve that data from database on button click using pure MVC.

Now how to retrieve that controls' value in controller.

#### In model:

```
public class Controls {
    public string ControlName{get;set;}
}
```

#### In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Controls> _controls=new List<Controls>();//retrieve 
    data from db in your case

    var _c=new Controls();
    _controls.Add(new Controls(){ControlName="textbox"});
    _controls.Add(new Controls(){ControlName="radio"});
    return View(_controls); // 
}
```

#### In view:

```
@model List<Controls>
@foreach(var item in Model) {
    <input type="@item.ControlName">
}
```

Comment: Your input does not have a `name` attribute so wont post back anything

Comment: but how to retrive that value in controller because controls are not binded with modal

Comment: Your model needs a property for the name of the control (you existing property is for the type of the control) Then you need to add a `name="@item.Name"`, but that will not bind to a collection anyway - refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand how to generate form controls for a collection (but there are so many other problems with your code and implementation that its impossible to know where to start)

Comment: I already add the name property to my unique code that is saved to the database against that control so how can i proceed for same